# Swift init method error: Declaration 'init(coder:)' cannot override more than one superclass declaration

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have many custom View in my project ( UIView's subclass). And I need to override `init` method.

I just want to `override init(frame: CGRect)` method. And I don't want to write the same code `init?(coder` in many UIView subclasses again and again.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

And I add an extension to UIView, then OK.

```
extension UIView{
    convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

The problem occurs, when I custom UITableView class.

```
class Table: UITableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    }
```

Xcode tips firstly,

> 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UITableView'

```
class Table: UITableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Xcode tips secondly,

> Declaration 'init(coder:)' cannot override more than one superclass declaration

---

How to fix it?

Comment: This is impossible. It's a required initializer. You have to write it everywhere when you override a different initializer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit your CustomTableView class from a BaseTableView Class which is a subclass of UITableView. BaseTableView class will contain both initialiser method of UITableView. Eg:

```
class BaseTableView: UITableView {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    }
}
```

Then your custom classes are inherited from BaseTableView class with a convenience override method of init(frame:...

```
class Table1: BaseTableView {
    convenience override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        self.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    }
}

class Table2: BaseTableView {
    convenience override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        self.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    }
}
```

we use convenience override init to convey that this is a convenience init that has the same signature as the designated initializer in the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Because `convenience init` and `required init` conflicted. You can not have more than one implementation for an initializer.